# npm run build parse error failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, html-parser

after the run command: npm run build,
i saw the error below in terminal.

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Error: Parse Error: <meta name="description" content="TextUtilsis a utility which can be used to manipulated your text in the way you want. />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
  
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />

   
  </html>

  - htmlparser.js:255 HTMLParser.parse
    [krn-app]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlparser.js:255:15

  - task_queues:95 process.processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5

  - htmlminifier.js:1282 async minify
    [krn-app]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:1282:3

  - htmlminifier.js:1365 async exports.minify
    [krn-app]/[html-minifier-terser]/src/htmlminifier.js:1365:16
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote character in the line where the build fails:

`<meta name="description" content="TextUtilsis a utility which can be used to manipulated your text in the way you want." />`